# Android Studio not recognizing wav files

Tags: android, android-studio, soundpool

I try to play some `wav` files in my project, but when i import the files into the raw directory they look like this:

[image]

What I'm supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question mark just means that Android Studio does not know what the default app is on your computer to play a .wav file. However, that does not affect Android Studio's usage of the .wav file; you'll still be able to build your app normally and use the audio files in your app.

Comment: Yeah, thank you, my bug was in another place. I would give you upvote if i could :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to be recognized by apps relying on media scanning, wav and mp3 files need to contain at least a valid "title" id(3) tag.

Check your file with the tool "eyeD3" which can be installed on debian based distros from the package: eyed3

If the title isn´t there, add it with:

```
eyeD3 -t yourtitle /path/to/mp3/file
```

You can check the title but I don´t think that is the problem...

Perhaps there´s no problem at all - if you put any files in raw, its icon will be question mark, but android studio can read it and do everything you need with the file.